# Redirection URL not working correctly with og tags

Tags: javascript, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph, twitter-card

I have given all og:tags and twitter tags correctly, but I am not able to redirect to url given in og:url from facebook and twitter

I have given this url https://wise-dolphin-87.localtunnel.me/content/kia5/us/en/vehicles/sorento/2019/gallery.share.html?imageUrl=https://wise-dolphin-87.localtunnel.me/content/dam/kia/us/en/vehicles/sorento/2019/lx/interior/gallery-sample-2.jpg&description=desc&url=https://wise-dolphin-87.localtunnel.me/content/kia5/us/en/vehicles/sorento/2019/gallery.html?gTabIndex=0&gimageIndex=2

expected to go to https://wise-dolphin-87.localtunnel.me/content/kia5/us/en/vehicles/sorento/2019/gallery.html?gTabIndex=0&gimageIndex=2 given in og:url but it is going to main url https://wise-dolphin-87.localtunnel.me/content/kia5/us/en/vehicles/sorento/2019/gallery.share.html?imageUrl=https://wise-dolphin-87.localtunnel.me/content/dam/kia/us/en/vehicles/sorento/2019/lx/interior/gallery-sample-2.jpg&description=desc&url=https://wise-dolphin-87.localtunnel.me/content/kia5/us/en/vehicles/sorento/2019/gallery.html?gTabIndex=0&gimageIndex=2

Comment: Can you explain the background of your problem a little more? What are you trying to do in broad terms andhow are you generating the URL that isn't working?

Comment: I am using Localtunnel to generate URL, so it works only for some time. The problem  is when I click the post on facebook which I shared, I am redirected to the URL which I have used to share the post,  not to the one I want to show